# SQL Server dynamically adding column names in the select query

Tags: sql-server

Below is my query

```
SELECT 
    P.PlanName
    V.Section
FROM 
    app.Plan P
CROSS APPLY 
    (VALUES ('Protective'), ('Effective'), ('EasyClaim')) V(Section);
```

in the query, this returns the value in `V.Section`, where as I want to get the value of that column from the table variable.

Comment: You don't need to `VALUES` table construct for this; just `JOIN` your table `app.Plan` to the table variable *that you don't show in your question) on `Plan`.

Comment: I can join the query to my table variable, but in my select query i still need  to mention the name of the column of my table variable whose data i need to fetch... That name of the column will be V.Section AS [Section]

Comment: Thee name of column will be in the table varuiable, @Sayan, it'll be columns names. You can't use row data to define the name of a column without dynamic SQL, and I doubt that's required. Your table variable should have 3 columns already, with the names `Protective`, `Effective`, and `EasyClaim`; there's no need for the `VALUES` table construct.

Comment: Your subquery that selects from your table variable is explicitly told to use V's value. `SELECT V.Section FROM @TabVariable WHERE Name = P.[PlanName]`. Assuming your table variable has a column named "Section", remove the `V.` from your Rating subquery. You will need to alias `@TabVariable` and reference that if the column names are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, you don't need the `VALUES` table construct; just `JOIN` to your table variable:

```sql
SELECT P.Plan,
       TV.Protective,
       TV.Effective,
       TV.EasyClaim
FROM app.Plan P
     LEFT JOIN @TableVariable TV ON P.Plan = TV.Plan; --I assume LEFT JOIN as otherwise you just want
                                                      --SELECT * FROM @TableVariable;
```

If you want the values for be `0` where the `JOIN` fails, then you use use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`. For example: `ISNULL(TV.Protective,0) AS Protective`

Comment: I used this query, this just returns 6 rows with my plan names and the sections and Protective, Effective, and EasyClaim as columns but where as i need Protective, Effective, and EasyClaim as rows beside each plan

Comment: I think it's time for sample data and expect results, @Sayan; you're not makign any sense here.